# Create URL routes in Esri Web AppBuilder (WAB)

Tags: routing, arcgis-web-appbuilder, url

I'm customizing my Esri Web AppBuilder portal to create an admin page where I can see analytics that I collect through a Python API that I created. The idea is that it is an administrative panel where I can make calls to API routes and configure my application. So far everything is ready, but I'm not sure if it's possible to create routes in my application, for example:
"example.com.br" is the domain of my application, I wanted that when accessing "example.com.br/admin_panel" I would go directly to the adminPanel widget where I would configure everything.

I wanted this widget to open on a blank screen, something similar to angular routing (https://angular.io/guide/routing-overview).

I read about dojo/hash and dojo/router (https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/hash/) and I don't know if it's possible to do what I want with it.

Could someone please clear this doubt?